# Where to place a downcast (prior to calling a method in the super class)?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I'm working on an assignment that uses the *UnfoldingMaps* library (http://unfoldingmaps.org/javadoc/index.html?overview-summary.html).

The assignment has a class called *CommonMarker*. This class inherits from the class *SimplePointMarker* which inherits from the class *AbstractMarker*. *AbstractMarker* implements the interface *Marker*.

I'm confused with casting that occurs in method *selectMarkerIfHover* that calls the *isInside* method.

Following is the skeleton code we have to complete. The objective is to set the instance variable *lastSelected* for the first Marker it finds that mouseX and mouseY is inside of. We are to use the *isInside( UnfoldingMap m, float x, float y )* method defined in the AbstractMarker abstract class to check if a location is inside a marker.

lastSelected is defined as:

```
private CommonMarker lastSelected;
```

The skeleton code given is:

```
private void selectMarkerIfHover(List<Marker> markers)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
    }
```

My solution is as below where I do downcasting just prior to assigning m to lastSelected.

```
for(Marker m:markers)
        {
            if(m.isInside(map, mouseX, mouseY))
            {
                m.setSelected(true);
                lastSelected = (CommonMarker)m;
                return;
            }
        }
```

The solution given by the instructor is slightly different from mine where downcasting is done even before inInside is called.

```
for (Marker m : markers) 
        {
            CommonMarker marker = (CommonMarker)m;
            if (marker.isInside(map,  mouseX, mouseY)) 
            {
                marker.setSelected(true);                   
                lastSelected = marker;
                return;
            }
        }
```

I'm not sure why the markers are 'downcasted' prior to calling the method isInside. Is this the best practice approach? Kindly share your thoughts, I'm pretty new to Java and I've tried to trace the code as much as I can but it's still quite overwhelming to me.

Comment: It's hard to answer without knowing which methods are defined in Marker interface and which methods are only defined in CommonMarker.

Comment: @Eran, isInside and setSelected are defined in the Marker interface.

Comment: I think your question title was misleading. I took the freedom to rework it. If you are not happy, just undo my change.

Comment: Your title sounds more relevant to my question. Thank you for editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is exactly one difference: your version will throw a ClassCastException when exactly that `m` which gives `true` for  `m.isInside(map, mouseX, mouseY)` is also **not** an instance of `CommonMarker`.

Whereas the second solution will throw that exception in case *any* of the markers in that List isn't a `CommonMarker` (to be precise: any object *prior* to some `m` that gives true for the if condition).

In that sense, there is a subtle difference in behavior. If that matters in your environment depends on your context. My gut feeling is: if that difference matters in your environment - then I would see this as a design smell and I would further investigate that context.

Beyond that: I think *both* options are "ok". But ideally you would make things even more explicit, like:

```
if (m instanceOf CommonMarker) {
  ... cast
} else {
  ... throw exception with meaningful error message
```

And of course: the second version has a minimal performance hit, as the cast is performed for each loop iteration; instead of just once. But instanceof/cast are both insignificant regarding performance.

Having said that: many people consider *downcasts* themselves to be a design smell. So, again - I would step back and figure if there are other options to avoid the downcast completely.

Comment: Great answer! But You should have added that downcasting itself is no good practice in the first place...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I thought about writing that, but got interrupted. Thanks - factored that in.